# How do I make an answer label box that checks your answer?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a question box label that looks likes a search box, however, I want the user be able to put in an answer to the question label and make it say something like if the answer was 'kfuffle' then go to youtube.com

Comment: Can you post the code that you've tried so far?

Comment: I don't have any code so far. I need the code for an answer/search box. (I know a search box needs some code like <input type="search>, that's all I've done) I then need some code (possible javascript) that checks the answer and makes it go to a certain link, as I said. "make it say something like if the answer was 'kfuffle' then go to youtube.com".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, pure JavaScript solution:

```
<div id="main">
Where to:<input type="search" id="search">
<button onclick="go()">Lets go</button>
```

```
<script>
function go(){
    var q = document.getElementById('search').value;
    switch(q){
        case 'kfuffle':
            window.location = 'https://youtube.com' ;
            break;
        case 'google':
            window.location = 'https://google.com';
            break;
        default:
            alert('Not found');
    }
}</script>
```

If you want to edit something, just google `switch javascript syntax`

PS: if you only need one option (the kfuffle one) just tell me and I'll edit the code so it's shorter and easier (done mine thinking about more than one option).

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

When the user clicks submit, it will check if their input is equal to 'kfuffle'. If so, a message is displayed and then after a little while, they're re-directed to YouTube.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if($_POST['text'] == 'kfuffle') {
echo "Correct answer!";
echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = 'http://www.youtube.com';\",1500);</script>";
}
}
?>

<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="text" style="border: 1px solid;">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```